# Spring asynchronous database interaction

Tags: java, spring

I have a spring application that uses multiple repositories to save objects in the database. The problem is that these actions are taking to long. Therefore, I want this to be asynchronous, but the actions should be executed in the order that the are created. I looked into possible solutions and did not find any solution that fits.

My idea or approach was to create a component that has a list of Runnables, it has to execute the Runnables if there are some in the list. This component should run from the application start until it stops. Other services can add Runnables to the list and the bean executes them. The Runnables contain the action for the database. I hope the example code makes it a little more clear what i want to achieve.

The Bean:

```
@Component
@Scope("singleton")
public class DatabaseHandler {
    private static final List<Runnable> transactions = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final Object lock = new Object();
    private boolean runHandler = true;

    @Async
    @PostConstruct
    public void runDBHandler() {
        System.err.println("Started handler!");

                while(runHandler) {
            while (transactions.size() == 0) {
                try {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        lock.wait();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    //do nothing
                }
            }
            transactions.get(0).run();
        }

    }

    public synchronized void addTransaction(Runnable transaction){
        transactions.add(transaction);
        lock.notify();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    void stop() {
        this.runHandler = false;
    }
}
```

Example service with Runnable:

```
@Service
public class ExampleService {

    @Autowired
    private ExampleRepository exampleRepository;

    @Autowired
    private DatabaseHandler databaseHandler;

    //some method that has to save a object
    public void someMethod(){
        // Create the object
        Object object = new Object();

        // Runnable that should save asynchronous
        Runnable runnable = ()->{
            exampleRepository.save(object);
        };
        // Give runnable
        databaseHandler.addTransaction(runnable);
    }

}
```

The problem with this code in particular is that I cannot use the locks in the class DatabaseHandler and get following exeption: Failed to load ApplicationContext. So my first question is why I cannot use the wait method? Is it wrong to make a while loop in this PostConstruct Annotation?

The other questions are more general: Is my idea bad? Can I solve my issue in a better way?

I hope my problem is understandable and has the proper format! (It is my first question)

I would be glad for any responses with help, comments or ideas. Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is the issue in the first place? Is it that the user is waiting too long until the operation finishes, and you would like to respond immediately, executing the operations in the background? Or is it that the inservtion operations aren't fast enough, and you want to make them faster?

Comment: Thank you for commenting! It is a application which has to react on price changes on a exchange and therefore be very fast. My boss said that he thinks the 100ms make a difference, if the application has to wait until the objects are saved. So yes the main object is to make it faster.

Comment: Then I don't see how queuing all the operations and executing them all one by one sequentially, rather than executing them in parallel (as you were doing it before) would solve anything, to the contrary.

Comment: I think what is missing is that the runnables should be sequentially executed by another thread and the main thread (or calling service) doesn't have to wait for the operation to finish.

Comment: Hence my original question. But you said that what mattered was that the operation had to be faster, not that the user (or calling service) had to avoid waiting. But suppose 10 threads are executing concurrently and all start the operation at the same time. How would you determine which has to execute first, and why should all their operations be done sequentially? You can of course execute everything asynchronously to avoid waiting. But queuing all the operations, even though they come from unrelated threads starting unrellated operations, will make things slower, not faster.

Comment: Sorry that I was not able to formulate it understandable.

So yes the calling entity should not wait, because the result is not important to it. The problem is that multiple services can save objects at the same time and the order is important at a later stage. But I just now realize that if the service creates a Runnable it should simply add a timestamp and then there is no problem with the order. So thank you for that. 
The problem is similar i think. I need a central point with some ThreadPool or something similar, because I cannot create a thread for every operation.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your use-case, but what's sure is that your code is not safe. You're reinventing the single thread pool executor. And the Async Spring support. You can just use an Async method with a single thread executor. That will be simpler, and safer.

Comment: Ok I will look into that thank you very much for your help.